# disable upload in rtorrent

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

Is it somehow possible to disable upload in `rtorrent`? One would think that `upload_rate = 0` might do the trick, but based on my tests and commented `rtorrent.rc` file in `rtorrent` source tarball, 0 is for unlimited speed. Or is *BitTorrent* protocol built in a way that at least some upload bandwidth is always required?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, you can setup upload connection to 0 or put 1kbps speed so it will use the minimum rate or even you can recompile the program by adding the file provided [here](http://citylight.thinkbay.net/Disable_sharing_in_rtorrent).

I do not want to be rude but did you consider what happen if everybody start doing same thing as you. The torrent work's with peer-to-peer connection. Therefore, by using a little upload from everyone, it help's other to download the file. Other's are depending on your upload to download the file as you are depending on others upload.

As explain the link above if you are worried about privacy, please note that even if you are not uploading, others can still tack you.

> **Remember**: people will STILL see you are connected to the tracker and if a client is using Superseeding, you will NOT GET ANY OTHER CHUNK of the file until you upload what you just downloaded to someone else! (which won't occur since you just disabled sharing).

Consider yourself warned.